# Why does this query work with an alias but the one without does not?

Tags: mysql

When I remove the aliases and replace all the s1s with order_status_updates and all the s2s with orders I get nothing in return.

This one works

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_status_updates AS s1 
JOIN orders AS s2 
WHERE s2.id = (SELECT MAX(s2.id) FROM orders) 
AND s1.order_id = s2.id 
AND s1.order_status_id = s2.order_status_id
```

This one does not

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_status_updates
JOIN orders
WHERE orders.id = (SELECT MAX(orders.id) FROM orders)
AND order_status_updates.order_id = orders.id
AND order_status_updates.order_status_id = orders.order_status_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't JOIN using the WHERE clause but the ON clause:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM order_status_updates AS s1 
  JOIN orders AS s2 
    ON s1.order_id = s2.id AND s1.order_status_id = s2.order_status_id
 WHERE s2.id = (SELECT MAX(s2.id) FROM orders);
```

Since `s2.id` in the WHERE clause refers to a single record, `SELECT max(s2.id) FROM orders` will result in `s2.id`. In other words, you can basically remove this condition.

The second query is different because here `MAX(orders.id)` refers to table `orders` mentioned in the FROM clause of the subquery. That is, `SELECT MAX(orders.id) FROM orders` will return the largest order ID.